# I cant insert data from a java program to laravel app via api

Tags: java, php, json, laravel, restful-authentication

I am new to laravel and I would like to save data to my online server via laravel api from a java program but I am getting errors.

this is my route on api.php:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});


Route::post('hooks','ApiTestController@store');
```

my ApiTestController: its just handles POST request then saves to the table.

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

            $postdata = json_decode($request->input('post_data'), true);
            $datas = $postdata['header'];
            $data = $datas[0];
            $testH = new TestH();
            $testH->test_date = $data['test_date'];
            $testH->expiration = $data['test_date'];
            $testH->source = $data['source'];


            $testH->save();

            return $testH;
   }
```

and my java code :

```
try {
    //local development server url
    URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/hooks");
    URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
    // activate the output
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(con.getOutputStream());

        //create the JSON String
        String json = null;
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        JSONWriter wr = new JSONWriter(sw);

        try {
            wr.object().key("header").array();

            wr.object();
            wr.key("test_date").value(new Date());
            wr.key("source").value("TEST");
            wr.key("expiration").value(new Date());


            wr.endObject();

            wr.endArray().endObject();
            json = sw.toString();
            System.out.println(json);
        } catch (JSONException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(WebConnectSample.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        // send to laravel server
        ps.print("post_data="+json);

        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) con;
        InputStream is;
        if (httpConn.getResponseCode() >= 419) {
            is = httpConn.getErrorStream();
        } else {
            is = httpConn.getInputStream();
        }

        // read the server reply
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            // close the print stream
        }
        ps.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

the thing is when I dont save via `$testH->save()` everything works fine. but if I include it java returns with the following error:

```
Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::addHeaders() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response, string given, called in C:\Users\relixusdev\Documents\WebProjects\tcmsite\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests.php on line 61
```

any idea what part causes the error? does it have to do with authentication? i just want to be able to save to the online database via my java program.

Comment: what version of laravel are you using?

Comment: Laravel Framework 5.6.15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if anyone comes here having the same problem, i found out that the problem is that I dont have the created_at and updated_at column at my table. I didn't realized its a requirement for laravel. silly me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Route group with prefix as below

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function() {
   Route::post('hooks','ApiTestController@store');
});
```

Comment: Same error. All it did was add another URI on routes:list

 api/api/hook